# Jelastic deployment manager drop down not working

Tags: deployment, jelastic

Earlier today I started the trial period with Jelastic, mainly to see if I can use it to deploy online my projects.

After I upload my .war file in the dashboard though, the **Deploy to** drop down doesn't appear. Same thing happens to the sample project as well. The drop down is absent.

Have tried with three different browsers, same weird "bug".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you create an environment? If yes, which servers are inside that environment? It sounds like you do not have an environment running that supports .war deployment.

Comment: I created the default environment they offer, the Auto Scalable Glassfish 4.1. It comes with load balancing and clustering out of the box. Shall I delete it and create my own?

Comment: You can find information about how to deploy an application in the Auto Scalable Glassfish in this article http://blog.jelastic.com/2016/08/16/how-to-configure-glassfish-cluster-with-automatic-load-balancing/ or just create your own environment.

Comment: @Jelastic thank you very much! Decided to create my own environment and successfully deployed a test app! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, deploying to a cluster is different than a single instance. So yes, I had to create my own environment (Glassfish and Postgresql) and the deployment manager works as intended :)